# Change column name in MariaDB

Tags: mariadb, spacebars

I have this column in this database with a spacebar included, which I want to change.

```
ALTER TABLE . CHANGE COLUMN `Anzahl Personen` AnzahlPersonen int(11);
```

After using this line in the command line the output is as following:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'CHANGE COLUMN `Anzahl Personen` AnzahlPersonen int(11)' at line 1
```

Yeah, I have no Idea, what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you are using dot (.) instead of table name that is why you have error.
You have to specify table name:

```
ALTER TABLE `table_name` CHANGE COLUMN `Anzahl Personen` AnzahlPersonen int(11);
```

Comment: `ALTER TABLE `table_name` CHANGE COLUMN `Anzahl Personen` AnzahlPersonen;`                      Does not work. The column datatype should be included even thought you don't plan to change it!

Answer (score 3):

`ALTER TABLE <table_name> CHANGE COLUMN old_name new_name column_definition`

https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-16290

Answer (score -1):

don't need to write single quotes on old column name

like:
ALTER TABLE table_name CHANGE COLUMN Anzahl Personen AnzahlPersonen int(11);