# How to rename a column name in maria DB

Tags: mysql, mariadb, rename, alter

I am new to SQL, I was trying to change column name in my database's table. I am using 'xampp' with 'maria DB' (OS - Ubuntu 18.04)

I tried all of the followings:

```
ALTER TABLE subject RENAME COLUMN course_number TO course_id;
ALTER TABLE subject CHANGE course_number course_id;
ALTER TABLE subject CHANGE 'course_number' 'course_id';
ALTER TABLE subject  CHANGE COLUMN 'course_number'  course_id varchar(255);
ALTER TABLE subject CHANGE 'course_number' 'course_id' varchar(255);
```

But the only output I got was:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'column course_number to course_id' at line 1

Could someone please tell me what is the correct answer. I have no idea what to do further.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change column name in MariaDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28507987/change-column-name-in-mariadb)

Comment: You should change the symbol from ' to  this `

Comment: thank you @ToujouAya. That was the mistake.

Comment: @JakeSteam It is a different from my question. He has messed up ' . '  with table name, in my case I was using the wrong symbol through out all the program.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Table names, column names, etc, may need quoting with backticks, but not with apostrophes (`'`) or double quotes (`"`).

```
ALTER TABLE subject
    CHANGE COLUMN `course_number`   -- old name; notice optional backticks
                   course_id        -- new name
                   varchar(255);     -- must include all the datatype info
```

Answer (score 31):

Starting with MariaDB 10.5.2 you should be able to do

```sql
ALTER TABLE subject RENAME COLUMN course_number TO course_id;
```

see https://mariadb.com/kb/en/alter-table/#rename-column

Comment: MariaDB [socialnet]> ALTER TABLE users RENAME COLUMN current_lat TO was_lat;<br/>
    ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'COLUMN current_lat TO was_lat' at line 1

Comment: @Michael, maybe you’re using the wrong version? You can show your version with `SELECT VERSION()`

Comment: 10.3.22-MariaDB-1:10.3.22+maria~xenial-log

Comment: I ended up using `change column`.

Comment: @MichaelrestoreMonicaCellio, yeah your version doesn't support the newer `RENAME COLUMN` way of doing it.

Answer (score 7):

```
alter table "table_name" change column "old_name" "New_name" "datatype"*;
```

there is no need to use "TO" between old_name & New_name  , datatype of New_name is must

e.g. -

```
alter table student change column id roll_no int;
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing this. I swore the documentation said to use 'TO' but after quadruple checking it doesn't have the 'TO' keyword. I was losing my mind! lol Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE subject CHANGE COLUMN course_number course_id VARCHAR(100);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).