# Renaming the column MySQL Workbench MariaDB

Tags: sql, mariadb

I would like to RENAME the column `item_id` this column is `int(11) UN zero-fill PK` I would like to rename to `agricultural_machine_id` I've tried this command

```
ALTER TABLE agricultural_machine CHANGE COLUMN `item_id` `agricultural_machine_id` int(11);
```

I run this command but don't appear if successful or failed.
[image]

When I run this command appear `item_id`

```
SELECT * FROM agricultural_machine;
```

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30290880/rename-a-column-in-mysql

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to rename a column name in maria DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53735305/how-to-rename-a-column-name-in-maria-db)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved put the schema together like `autoparanaiba.TABLE_NAME`.